# MVC Model regex allow five whitespace character

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

```
 [RegularExpression("^\\d{5}$||d{0}", ErrorMessage = "Girdiğiniz değer 5 karakter uzunluğunda olmalıdır ve rakamlardan oluşmalıdır")]
 public string PostaKodu { get; set; }
```

When I get PostaKodu from old database , it returns value as five space character if it is null. In form view, it gives validation error. How can i add five white space character to my regular expression

Comment: Space charater is `\s` so `\s{5}` should be ok.

Comment: `\s` is whitespace not space

Comment: @abc123 i did not know difference between whitespace and space but \s worked.

Comment: @user2688655 `\s` includes spaces, tabs, and line breaks

Comment: @Rolice Thanks for answer it worked. Can you write it as answer to set accepted answer
    "^\\d{5}$||d{0}||^\\s{5}$"

Comment: @abc123, I search it on net, and i learned it, and I've understood whiteSpace is correct definition for my problem:)

Comment: Yes I will write one. :) @abc123, tabs should be `\t`, newlines are `\n` and carriage return should be `\r`, as in standard programming. Check the modifiers of the expression - it may include newlines from specific modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your expression like use spaces like `\s`, this is the character for white space in regular expression. Something like `\\d{5}$||d{0}||^\\s{5}$` would do the job :D